# what is difference between SingleRow and SingleResult in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

in c# what is the difference between both.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with either class. Where do they live?  What assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine single result will be one single value

whereas single row will be some form of array of values.

Comment: btw check out linq2sql and entity framework. I havent used ado.net for a couple of years. They save a lot of time with the dal if they can be used in your situation